# How to cross reference 2 shapefiles of road segments?

Tags: gis, shapefile, geopandas

I have 2 shapefiles that represent roads, let's call them shapes A and B. Each road is represented as line segments. File B is almost a superset of the other, with just a few roads of A not represented. File A with one segment selected (in red):

[image: File A with one segment selected (in red)]

In this superset file (B), the segments are smaller. I can say that for every segment in A there are one or more segments in B. I believe there isn't a segment in B that corresponds to more than one segment in A. Here is shapefile B with one segment selected (in red):

[image: Shapefile B with one segment selected (in red)]

The line coordinates aren't exact, just very near each other. Here are the coordinates of the leftmost dot of the selected line:

```
Dot in file A: -42.92896076999995 , -22.77139965999993
Dot in file B: -43.217942900516830, -22.888565009926047
```

I'm using **geopandas**.

How would I cross-reference the two datasets? For each line segment in file B find the associated segment in file A (if it exists)?

Answer (score 0):

The question seems to depend on what you are using as a standard for cross-references. For example, you must first decide whether to assume a case where each segmentation intersects or whether to define it as the minimum distance between each segmentation.

Anyway, using geopandas or shapely for both is not a difficult task. After dividing all the segmentation of A into individual linestrings, you can use the overlay function of geopandas to find the occurrence of even a slight intersection with the segmentation of B.

You will have to decide whether to find the shortest distance orthogonal or the shortest distance between the start point and end point of each segmentation. You can use from shapely.ops import nearest_points etc. You can use all the features of shapely to target the geometry of geopandas.